# Pasar parámetros de un formulario al modal bootstrap

Tags: php, modal

Buenas tardes,

Estoy teniendo un problema al pasar datos de un formulario a un modal y no se si lo estoy haciendo bien, o si hay algo mal.

Básicamente, tengo una tabla para el listado de establecimientos. Puedes editarlos, eliminarlos y añadir nuevos desde esa tabla. este es el código HMTL.

```
<td class="col-md-3">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $CRDomain; ?>assets/functions/settings/library/update.php" style="float:left">
            <input type="hidden" value="establecimiento" name="action" />
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $Establecimiento['IDEstablecimiento']; ?>" name="id" />
            <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-xs green" style="margin:5px;"/>
        </form>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $CRDomain; ?>assets/functions/settings/library/delete.php" style="float:left">
            <input type="hidden" value="establecimiento" name="action" />
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $Establecimiento['IDEstablecimiento']; ?>" name="id" />
            <input type="submit" value="Remove" class="btn btn-xs red-thunderbird" style="margin:5px;" data-toggle="confirmation" data-placement="right" />
        </form>
    </div>
</td>
```

Y este es el código del archivo update, que mira si la acción es establecimiento, y si hay una ID hará el update, y si no me lleva a la página de nuevo abriendome el modal para el edit.

```
if ($action == "establecimiento") {

    if ($_POST["id"] != "") {

        $id = secure($_POST["id"], $conectar);

        header("location: ../../../../administration/settings/library.php");

    } else {
        header("location: ../../../../administration/settings/library.php#establecimiento");
    }

}
```

El problema es que te lleva a la página pero no abre el modal.

También preguntar, ¿Esta bien hacerlo así, o hay alguna manera más rápida y sencilla?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes controlar si existe un hash en la url y abrir el modal en caso de que exista.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (window.location.hash && $(window.location.hash).length) {
        $(window.location.hash).modal('show');
    }
});
```

Obviamente el hash de la url tiene que ser el id del modal que quieres abrir.